# Splitting a String at the beginning of a line

Tags: java, regex

I have a text that i want to split whenever i encounter "WORD" at the
beginning of a line and with no characters following it. I used
text.split("WORD"), only its not good because for example %hi hi WORD should not be matched by the split method, and right now it is matched.
i tried using "^WORD" but that only matches WORD at the beginning of the entire text.

any ideas how do i do that?
btw i use java if that matters

Comment: Can you post sample input text?

Comment: You mean, you want to split _by WORD_ if you see WORD on a line all by itself (i.e. no characters before because it's at the beginning, and no characters after it on the line either)? Or split by WORD except where it occurs on its own line at the very end of the file (literally no characters following)? Or you want to split by something else? I'm confused.

Comment: its like you said, when its on a line by itself

Answer (score 5):

Use the [multiline modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) (which has the same effect as the `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag for a regex pattern):

```
text.split("(?m)^WORD");
```

It changes the meaning of `^` from *"at the beginning of the string"* to *"at the beginning of a line"*.

Comment: hi. it doesn't work for me. i still matches sdfsdWORD for example

Comment: The question still isn't perfectly clear, but I think you need the `$` anchor at the end, too.

Comment: @Alan: Possibly. In any case it would not match `"sdfsdWORD"`, so I'm not really sure what the OP is doing.

Answer (score 0):

As Tomalak posted, use the multiline modifier. If you want to keep the WORD itself you could also do:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(^WORD .*$)", Pattern.MULTILINE);
String input = "WORD something. And WORD not at beginning.\nWORD something.";
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
   System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Encountering "WORD" at the beginning of a line and with no characters following it.

`text.split("(?mis)^WORD(?!.)");`

Comment: @Tomalak yot didn't precise if WORD would be always upper case. I wanted dot to match ANY characters.

Comment: With the `s` modifier, `(?!.)` means no character follows this point, not even a newline.  In other words, it matches the very end of the string, exactly like `\z`.